# Another word for someone who uses what they have on hand for purposes other than their original intention

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word akin to resourceful, but I can't put my finger on it. Over the weekend, there were acquaintances that had limited resources on hand and used many of the objects for purposes other than their original intention.

Can anyone help me identify a word for this?

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Would you consider if we narrow it down to using the object deliberately in an unintended manner?  Or using an object in an unintended manor due to ignorance, necessity or laziness? (or some combination?)

Comment: I don't know why this was closed. The question seems clear  enough, even without a sample sentence. And I think Jim Mack's answer nailed it.

Answer (score 2):

You might be thinking of ***[MacGyvering](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-does-macgyver-mean-slang-definition)***, which as the M/W link says, is a slang term for making do with what's on hand.

Answer (score 1):

**Jury rigging** (sometimes **jerry rigging**) is defined by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_rigging) as "makeshift repairs made with only the tools and materials at hand", and by Merriam-Webster ([jury-rig, verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jury-rig)) as "to erect, construct, or arrange in a makeshift fashion"

One of the meanings of **improvise** (noun **improvisation**) is according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/improvising) "to make or fabricate out of what is conveniently on hand".